# Struggling to get the Sum() function to output one value from a list

Tags: python

```
olst = []
elst = []

E = int(input("Please enter your first number:  "))
O = int(input("Please enter your second number:  "))
for OS in range(E,O+1):
    if(OS%2!=0):
        olst.append(OS)

for ES in range(E,O+1):
    if(ES%2==0):
        elst.append(ES)

    print("Sum of all odd values is:  ", sum(olst))
    print("Sum of all even values is:  ", sum(elst))
```

This programs intention is to print the sum of all odd numbers between my two integers as well as the even. This is my current code, I'm fairly new to python and tinkering around, open to any criticism and tips. The main issue I'm having is when I run my program both sum(olst) and sum(elst) output the answer multiple times until they reach the correct and final answer. Get the feeling my process is fundamentally flawed somewhere early on but hoping that's not the case!

Comment: You put your `print()` calls inside the loop, so naturally they will be executed each time thorugh the loop. If you don't want that behavior, put them outside the loop. Hint: they're inside the loop because they're indented.

Comment: Ah awesome that was an easy fix, thank you so much.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two lines with the `print` statements should not be indented - otherwise, they are located within the `for` loop and executed multiple times:

```
olst = []
elst = []

E = int(input("Please enter your first number:  "))
O = int(input("Please enter your second number:  "))
for OS in range(E,O+1):
    if(OS%2!=0):
        olst.append(OS)

for ES in range(E,O+1):
    if(ES%2==0):
        elst.append(ES)

print("Sum of all odd values is:  ", sum(olst))
print("Sum of all even values is:  ", sum(elst))
```

There are also many ways how this code can be optimised (for example, you don't really need the lists `elst` and `olst` and can compute the sums in the loop or use comprehensions), but that's a different issue.

Comment: I tried to do it without elst and olst but putting sum(OS) and sum(ES) came up saying ints are not iterable, or something of that variety. Is there a simpler way to solve that issue?

Comment: @nedarb, if you don't use a list you would do the sum incrementally within the loop. Set a variable to zero before the loop, then add to the variable (ie `x = x + OS` or `x += OS`) instead of appending to the list. Then you don't need the sum function.

Answer (score 0):

You already got your answer above but since you mentioned you are open to tips, this is to provide you just an alternate solution using **list comprehensions**:

```
E = int(input("Please enter your first number:  "))
O = int(input("Please enter your second number:  "))

olst = [i for i in range(E, O+1) if i%2  == 1]  
elst = [i for i in range(E, O+1) if i%2  == 0]  

print("Sum of all odd values is:  ", sum(olst))
print("Sum of all even values is:  ", sum(elst))
```

Additionally, you can replace the middle two lines of the code by

```
olst = [i for i in range(E, O+1) if i%2 ]  
elst = [i for i in range(E, O+1) if not i%2]
```